# How do I reference an object in a different function?

Tags: python

I have a Class items, a Class rooms and a Class game file.
In the game class file's **init** I call 2 functions named create_item and create_room.

The trouble appears when I try to call a item class function in the create_room function called "self.set_floor(self, item_on_floor)", which simply . eg:
`testroom.set_floor(testobj1)`

If I have the create_item and create_room functions combined as one, it knows I'm referring to the object "testobj1" of the item class, but when they are two separate functions, it gives me the error:

> name 'testobj1' is not defined<

Here's the relevant parts of my three files if you are interested

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inv_list = []
        self.create_item()
        self.create_rooms()
    def create_item(self):
        testobj1 = thing("testobj1-", "an obj1 for testing", 1, True, "F")
        testobj2 = thing("testobj2-", "an obj2 for testing", 1, True, "F")
        self.add_to_inventory(testobj2)
        testobj3 = thing("testobj3-", "an obj3 for testing", 1, False, "F")
        testobj4 = thing("testobj4-", "an obj4 for testing", 1, True, "F")
    def create_rooms(self):
        testroom = Room("a room for testing.")
        testroom2 = Room("a second room for testing")
        testroom.set_floor(testobj1)       #This is where the error shows up
        testroom.set_floor(testobj3)
        testroom2.set_floor(testobj4)
    def add_to_inventory(self, itemI):
        self.inv_list.append(itemI)

class thing():
    def __init__(self, thing_name, item_desc, weight, moveability, exist):
        self.thing_name = thing_name
        self.item_desc = item_desc
        self.weight = weight
        self.moveability = moveability
        self.type = exist
class Room():
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description
        self.exits = {}
        self.floor_thing = []
        self.check_event = ""
    def set_floor(self, itemF):
        self.floor_thing.append(itemF)
```

to clarify, this is supposed to be a text based game. the testrooms will be replaced with forest, volcano, desert, etc. and test items will be replaced with various in game items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this, but one way is to let  `create_item` *return* the object it created, and then to pass on that value where it is needed. If it is only needed in `create_rooms`, then why not call it from there:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inv_list = []
        # don't call create_item here. Leave that to create_rooms:
        self.create_rooms()  
    def create_item(self):
        # return the created object:
        return thing("testobj1-", "an obj1 for testing", 1, True, "F")
    def create_rooms(self):
        testroom = Room("a room for testing.")
        testroom.set_floor(self.create_item())  # call it here
```

You can do that at a different level as well:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inv_list = []
        # Communicate the result of create_item to create_rooms:
        self.create_rooms(self.create_item())  
    def create_item(self):
        # return the created object:
        return thing("testobj1-", "an obj1 for testing", 1, True, "F")
    def create_rooms(self, item):  # extra parameter
        testroom = Room("a room for testing.")
        testroom.set_floor(item)
```

...etc. There are really many ways to make this happen.

### Edit - after question update

When you have more items, then don't assign them to separate variables. Instead put them in a list. Then the same principle as above can be applied:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inv_list = []
        self.create_rooms(self.create_items())  # pass on the list of objects
    def create_items(self):  # give method name plural name
        testobjects = [
            thing("testobj1-", "an obj1 for testing", 1, True, "F"),
            thing("testobj2-", "an obj2 for testing", 1, True, "F"),
            thing("testobj3-", "an obj3 for testing", 1, False, "F"),
            thing("testobj4-", "an obj4 for testing", 1, True, "F")
        ]
        self.add_to_inventory(testobjects[1])
        return testobjects  # return them all
    def create_rooms(self, testobjects):
        testroom = Room("a room for testing.")
        testroom2 = Room("a second room for testing")
        for testobj in testobjects[0:2]:
            testroom.set_floor(testobj)
        testroom2.set_floor(testobjects[3])
```

Comment: but what if I'm creating 20 rooms with 50 items in them?

Comment: Can you update your question to make a representative example? You certainly will need to make `create_item` more generic, as it looks like it will make the same kind of object each time...

Comment: I have updated the post. Yes the items and rooms will be many different objects sharing the same set of attributes. but each with different values

Comment: So you create a specific variable for each item? That looks quite hard-coded to me. Is there no need to have it more dynamic?

Comment: See update of answer in light of your updated question.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you meant by more dynamic. I need each item to have the attributes of "name, description, weight, moveability, how it come to exist".

Comment: I was referring to the variable names: `testobj1`, `testobj2`. I would expect that these items (in a real game scenario) would come to exist during the game/session and you would have a hard time to assign those to hard-coded variable names. You should use a list or dictionary or some other sort of collection data structure.